# What is the difference between AttributeRoutingConfig and RouteConfig in MVC5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

To understand the code behind the AttributeRoutingConfig I'm trying to recreate it using RouteConfig

AttributeRoutingConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Routing;
using AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc;

[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SimplestAuth.AttributeRoutingConfig), "Start")]

namespace xyz
{
    public static class AttributeRoutingConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) 
        {                
            routes.MapAttributeRoutes();
        }

        public static void Start() 
        {
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        }
    }
}
```

RoutingConfig.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace xyz
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for information to understand the differences and similarities between the two techniques. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

They both do essentially the same thing:

> They register your routes to the **RouteTable**.

- The first code sample you have above utilizes **AttributeRouting** so it does an assembly scan.
- The second code sample you have utilizes the **RouteTable** directly, so it is a much more manual looking process.

Hope that helps.